# Is there a criterion for compactness in $L^\infty(\Omega)$ with strong topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

If such criterion exists, since $C(\Omega)$ is closed in $L^\infty(\Omega)$, and if $\Omega$ is bounded and closed, the Ascoli-Arzela theorem has given a sufficient and necessary condition，means this criterion needs more requirements than  Ascoli-Arzela theorem. So my questions:

1. How to generalize the compactness condition in $L^\infty(\Omega)$($\Omega$ is compact in $R^N$)?
2. If $\Omega$ is not compact, or just $R^N$, what is the compactness criterion?

Thank you!

Comment: Compactness of $\Omega$ can't be relevant here - $L^\infty(\Omega)$ only depends on the measure algebra of $\Omega$, and that's the same for every positive-measure set $\Omega$, so all $L^\infty(\Omega)$ are isomorphic (except the trivial ones where it is zero-dimensional).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955394/compact-subsets-of-l-infty.  Surprise surprise: the place to look is Dunford and Schwartz.

Comment: Thanks, but why all $L^\infty(\Omega)$ are isomorphic? if $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are topologically isomorphic, the isomorphism between $L^\infty(\Omega_1)$ and $L^\infty(\Omega_2)$ is trivial. P.s. the criterion in Dunford and Schwartz's book seems very hard to apply, sad...

Comment: Topological isomorphism is neither necessary or sufficient.  What you need is a bimeasurable map that takes null sets to null sets.  If $\Omega$ is the standard measure-zero Cantor set and $\Omega'$ is a positive-measure "fat" Cantor set, then they are homeomorphic but $L^\infty(\Omega) = 0$ while $L^\infty(\Omega')$ is infinite dimensional.  Conversely, $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $\Omega' = [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ are not homeomorphic but they have the same $L^\infty$.

Comment: Thanks again, but how to construct a bi-measurable function which takes null sets to null sets?

Comment: Well, a simpler example is $[0,2]$ versus $[0,1] \cup (2,3]$; just split $[0,2]$ in half and move one half over.  To get to $[2,3]$ instead of $(2,3]$, take some countable set $C = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots\}$ in $(2,3]$, let $x_0 = 2$, and consider the map that fixes $C^c$ and maps $x_n$ to $x_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 5):

There is simple, elementary characterisation as follows: firstly, as mentioned in comments, a topology on $\Omega$ is arguably a red herring so I will consider a space with a $\sigma$-algebra and a $\sigma$-finite measure. Then a closed, bounded subset $B$ is compact in the corresponding $L^\infty$ space if and only if for each positive $\epsilon$ there is a finite partition  $(A_i)$ of $\Omega$ into disjoint, measurable sets so that the variation of each $f$ in $B$ is less than  $\epsilon$ (i.e., $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \epsilon$ a.e. on each $A_i$).

Comment: I believe we can prove it using the density of simple functions in $L_\infty$. Since it holds for all measure spaces, why is it that we require a $\sigma$-finite measure space?

Comment: In case that anybody is looking for a reference for this result: It is proved (in a slightly different formulation though) in the article "B. M. Cherkas: Compactness in $L^\infty$ spaces (1970)" ([link to zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0194.43601)).